# Write logical expression that would equal TRUE

Tags: c++, logic

Initial numbers: that are three ones - a, b, and c.

Task: to write a logical expression that would be equal TRUE (would be shown 1 in screen), then and only then when:

a) all of the variables - a, b, c - meanings are the same.
b) all of the variables - a, b, c - meanings aren't the same (they are all different).
c) two of the three variables meanings are the same.
d) all of the variables - a, b, c - are even numbers.
e) all of the three variables meanings are positive, but not bigger than 100.

This is how I have written the a) task:

```
int main() 
{

    int n;
    unsigned int a, b, c;

    cout << "Write three numbers: " << endl;
    cout << "First: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Second: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Third: " << endl;
    cin >> c;

    {
    for (a=1, b=2, c=3; a,b,c>0; a++, b++, c++);
    }

    n=a||b||c;
    cout << n << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It does not work, and I am sure I have made some mistakes.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're trying to achieve with all that code. Frankly, it seems to me that you're throwing stuff in randomly. Trust me, that never works. Think before you code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding given assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this looks like an assignment, I'll suggest a couple of things.

As `templatetypedef` has pointed out, you need to go back to understand C++ syntax a bit.

However, I'm not sure that you have clarified to yourself what you want to do.  The fact that you have a loop in there is a tip-off.

I recommend writing out what you need to do in pseudocode -- just plain English statements that show some logic and procedure.

I'll do this for part a).  Something like this:

```
Accept user input for three values
If all three values are the same
    Return true
Otherwise
    Return false
```

Looking at this, is it necessary to have a loop for part a)?  Probably not.

Maybe it's something like this instead?

```
if (a == b && b == c) // if all values are the same
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @John,

Have figured it out like this:



int main()
{
    int n;
    unsigned int a, b, c;
    cout<<"Write a number: "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    a=b=c;
    if (a == b && b == c);
    n= (a ==b) && (b ==c);
    cout<<n<<endl;


    return 0;
}


It works now!

Answer (score 4):

This loop has a lot of issues:

```
for (a=1, b=2, c=3; a,b,c>0; a++, b++, c++);
```

First, notice that you have a semicolon at the end of the loop, meaning that that the loop has no effect. It's equivalent to

```
for (a=1, b=2, c=3; a,b,c>0; a++, b++, c++) {
     // Do nothing
}
```

Next, your conditional is

```
a, b, c > 0
```

This does not mean "a, b, and c are greater than 0." Instead, it uses the comma operator, which means "evaluate all these expressions, but discard the values of all but the last." It's therefore equivalent to

```
for (a=1, b=2, c=3; c > 0; a++, b++, c++) {
     // Do nothing
}
```

Finally, notice that you are *incrementing* `c` in this loop, which means that the loop will continue to run until `c` overflows.

What's weirder is that you're reading in values for `a`, `b`, and `c` from the user but then immediately overwriting them in the loop. Is that what you intended?

I don't know what you intended to do here, but this should probably explain what the program ***is*** doing, from which you might able to learn why it ***isn't*** doing what you want it to do.

Hope this helps!